# matplotlib plot outside window

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, pyqt5

I just updated my Anaconda packages since I would like to use **PyQt5** instead of PyQt4. Before this update, I was able to use the command `%matplotlib qt`. My plot appeared in a separate window.

Since, I did the update, I get the following error: `No module named PyQt4`

Did I mess up something or do I have to use another command with the PyQt5 version?

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: change your default backend to qt5agg.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond. It works.